# Wildcard SSL common name - can it be called anything?

Tags: ssl-certificate

I was just wondering if a wildcard SSL certificate necessarily needs to have a common name that contains the domain name of the sites that need the SSL certificate applied to.

For example, for the following:

Domain name: **testdomain.com**

Subsites:

- www.testdomain.com
- mobile.testdomain.com
- mytestenvironment.testdomain.com

Do I necessarily need my wildcard certificate to have a common name of `*.testdomain.com`?

Comment: serverfault.com might be a better place for this question.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yes, your common name should be *.yourdomain.com for a wildcard certificate.

Basically, the Common Name is what states what domain your certificate is good for, so it has to specify the actual domain.

Clarification: It shouldn't "contain" the domain name of the sites, it should **be** the domain of the sites. I'm guessing there is no difference in your question, I just wanted to clarify, in case there's a misconception of what the domain should be, or what the certificate will be used for.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you should use `dnsName` entries in the `subjectAltName` section of the certificate to specify the FQDNs, not the CN part of the `subject`. Using the `subject` for this purpose has been deprecated since RFC 2818 has been published in 2000. Quoting [section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
> be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
> field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.

The only case where the contents of the `subject` are relevant in the context of server certificate validation is if there is no `dnsName` included in the `subjectAltName`, a case which has been deprecated for the past 17 years at the time of writing.

Usage of wildcard certificates is deprecated, as shown by [section 7.2 of RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-7.2):

> This document states that the wildcard character '*' SHOULD NOT be
> included in presented identifiers but MAY be checked by application
> clients (mainly for the sake of backward compatibility with deployed
> infrastructure).

Using the same private key for several services is usually considered bad practice. Should one of the services be compromised, communications from other services will be at risk and you'll have to to replace the key (and certificate) for all services.

I suggest RFC 6125 as a good source of information on this matter.

Comment: "And so are wildcard certificates": could you please elaborate? `dnsName` can contain a wildcard domain. Also, what should be in `subject` in that case?

Comment: Have a look at RFC 6125 sections [1.5](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-1.5) and [7.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125#section-7.2). As long as the `subjectAltName` contains at least one `dnsName`, the contents of the `subject` are irrelevant in the context of certificate verification.

Comment: @WoJ I have edited my answer. I hope this is all clearer now.